# laravel-show profile user for custom authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My custom auth is 'penyewa' and i work for multi table authentication. So, how to show profile user(like id, username, name, etc.) for custom auth. I try to show on view but i got error message after login like this

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::$id (View: C:\wamp64\www\sigorugm1\privasisigorugm\resources\views\pesan.blade.php)

Controller

```
    public function pesanLapangan()
{ 
  $penyewa = Penyewa::find(auth('penyewa'));
//or $penyewa = Penyewa::find(Auth::guard('penyewa')->user());
  return view('pesan')->with('penyewa',$penyewa);}
```

view

```
@if(auth('penyewa'))
                <h3>Halo, {{auth('penyewa')->nama_penyewa}}</h3>
                @endif
```

Comment: Show us the code that *caused* that error. C'mon.

Comment: sorry i forget insert the code.i have edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check and access user's properties from user object instance, not guard instance. Change your view to this:

```
@if(auth('penyewa')->check())
    <h3>Halo, {{auth('penyewa')->user()->nama_penyewa}}</h3>
@endif
```

Comment: I think your `auth('penyewa')` is returning null. Oh, and please update your question for what you have tried, and show line of code that caused it.